# Missing Easing function in Minified jQuery UI Build

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

If I include the full source build of jQuery UI from the CDN:
//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js

Then all the scripts on my site work fine.

On the other hand, if I use the jQuery UI builder download page and I include EVERYTHING to make a custom.min.js file and include it,

Then I get
TypeError: x.easing[this.easing] is not a function @ http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.0:6

Again: the only difference is whether I include the non-minified from the CDN or my locally hosted minified file built with everything from the jQueryUI site.  As in this code:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-custom', 'js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.full.custom.min.js', array(), '1.0', false ); 
//wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js', array(), '1.0', false );
```

Uncommenting one and commenting the other fixes the problem, but both should work.

Site in question is here:
http://a1.nbksite.com/

Has anyone else experienced a problem dealing with the custom built jQuery UI library like this?

Comment: You mean you're using this [builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/)?

Comment: Yes, my file jquery-ui-1.10.3.full.custom.min.js is built using the jQuery UI download page.  It contains everything.

Comment: it appears you are also getting an error that it can't find your `jquery -1.10.2.min.map`. I think jQueryUI simply extends off the easing function from jQuery so that might be the source of the problem?